# Is it possible to hyperlink text output using c++?

Tags: c++, hyperlink, libcurl

I want to output some hyperlinked text to a file using C++. I want the text to be "clickable" so that when a user clicks the "text" it'll take him to a specified, linked webpage. I was trying to make sense of libcurl, but from what I understand it doesn't allow you to output the links in the way i'm describing. For example, I want to output a list of separate links,

- Cookie
- Cake
- Pie

that all go to different webpages. If i'm wrong, i'll do some more learning, but if not, i'd like to hear other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Hypertext does not work in a standard console.  You'll need to create a web page and send to a browser; or contact the web server directly.

Comment: Also, in *standard* C++, there is no event generated for a mouse click; the language has no support for mice.  You'll need to use platform (operating system) API to deal with mice.

Comment: I suggest you place an [HTML Hyperlink](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) into your file.  It's text, so a simple output to a file should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice. Can you clarify what you mean by "contact the web server directly" though?

Comment: There are libraries you can use to talk with web page servers.  Rather than writing to a file, develop a GUI that can receive mouse clicks and when the mouse click event is received, contact the web page server.  Some GUI frameworks have HTML Hyperlink widgets (which lessens the work you have to do).

Comment: Ah I understand. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you are going to generate a text file, you can do so and place hyperlinks in that. But how those hyperlinks are interpreted depends on the program that you use to open the text file. For example the web browser detect the hyperlinks and make them clickable links but notepad does not know anything about the clicking on the hyperlinks.

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep that in mind